# Problem installing Arabic on 18.04

Tags: language-support, arabic, rtl

I have correctly followed the steps of installing Arabic [from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language-install.html.en)

The letters "en" and "ar" show on the top right of the screen.

However, it has no effect. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you want your desktop be displayed in Arabic, you need to [select Arabic as the display language](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html) also.

Comment: I had nothing extra to do. It was apparently a bug. A few days ago, there was an automatic update that required restarting. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Arabic language worked with me after doing these:

1. Adding all the available options for Arabic (qwerty, azerty, etc).
2. Switching between all of them to see which one will work.
3. Once one of them worked fine and Arabic letters has been wrote, all the other Arabic options worked with me.

I think it may needs some time to take effect for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

To add Arabic letters,

1. Open Settings
2. Region & Language
3. Under Input Sources, click on the (+) icon.
4. Select "Arabic (AZERTY)"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnJMb.png)